# Change iOS App List of Supported Languages in App Store

Tags: ios, xcode, localization, app-store, app-store-connect

I've noticed that several of my apps have multiple supported languages (all of them I assume) in the "Languages" section of the App Store. However, the only language I actually support is English. How do I change this?

I searched online and found that the different `.iproj` folders in the Bundle decides what languages are listed on the App Store, but both my apps only have `en.iproj` so that didn't help me much.

**EDIT 1:**

I went to the Binary Info section in iTunes Connect, and took a screenshot that shows my problem. 
[image]

Comment: Do they appear as 'Active', or as languages that you can 'activate'? I think it has more to do with the language of the store UI, the description etc. not necessarily the languages supported by the binary.

Comment: Neither, this is on the actual App Store for customers to see. Under the description is a list of languages, and for some Apps only english (or plus a few other languages) are shown. For my English-only App, all the languages are shown.

Comment: I see. I just checked my app on the store, and it only lists the languages I have added localization for.

Comment: I never added localization for *any* languages, and that might be my problem. How/ where do you list the languages that are supported specifically?

Comment: Weird. After checking iTunes connect, it looks like you can add/remove supported languages (popup menu to the right, under the 'Versions' tab), but only for **upcoming** versions (not the one on the store). Perhaps you'll need to push an update...

Comment: If we are looking at the same place (under "new Version" under the "Versions" tab), that's the place for the localization of the Metadata (such as description, images, name etc.). The "Languages" section I'm talking about should describe the languages the App and its content supports, if I'm not mistaken

Comment: Yes, under the 'Save' button in my case (I already have a 'next' version). That popup lets you chose which language version of the metadata (description, screenshots, keywords etc) you are editing on iTunes connect. You can only add/remove languages (other than the primary, I think) in next (unpublihed) versions. I still don't know what led your app to support so many languages you didn't specify, but perhaps you can remove them in an upcoming version. Other than than, contact Apple...

Comment: I tried contacting Apple, but actually getting to the contact form in iTunes Connect is harder than I remember... I just get to the frequently asked questions section by choosing a category that fit my request

Comment: Actually, I looked through my projects one more time - and I found that deep inside a "Supporting Files" folder for a 3rd party service (**UserVoice**) I'm including in my app, is localizations for all the languages listed on the App Store. 

That might just have caused the languages listed on the store. Thanks anyways :)

Comment: Did you find a way to remove the languages from the listing in the appstore?

Comment: @natanavra Yes, turned out to be my fault. The App Store automatically detects what languages your App supports based on what localization files are included in the Bundle. Due to a 3rd-party service, I had localizations for all these languages, but just didn't know it. I just removed those files, resubmitted to the App Store, and it's now gone :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I looked through my projects one more time - and I found that deep inside a "Supporting Files" folder for a 3rd party service (**UserVoice**) I'm including in my app, is localizations for all the languages listed on the App Store. That might just have caused the languages listed on the store.

Comment: Good that you found it! Third party software always has some pitfalls. Perhaps in a future update you can remove the supporting files on the library for the languages that your app does not support.

Comment: Same issue here, though it was Urban Airship that was to blame. (Airship/UI/Default/Common/Resources). Previously I've also had the issue from either Flurry or Crashlytics I believe.

Answer (score 3):

[image: edit app store supported languages list in xcode]

You can edit the list of supported languages that appears in the app store from x code. Go to project > Info > Localizations to add or remove languages from that list.