# Are extra localizations in Apple's ResearchKit causing the iOS App Store to incorrectly assume that our app is localized for many extra languages?

Tags: ios, localization, researchkit

We just release an app based on Apple's ResearchKit.  In the App Store, the listing indicates that the app supports many different languages, although we only specified two in the metadata in iTunesConnect.

This question,  [Change iOS App List of Supported Languages in App Store](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27240901/change-ios-app-list-of-supported-languages-in-app-store), seems to indicate that the extra languages could have been automatically detected because there are .lproj folders in a third-party framework that our app uses.  ResearchKit does have many .lproj folders for localization.

Has anyone else with a ResearchKit app run into this?  Is the only solution to pull these extra folders out of the ResearchKit framework?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're correct. You'll need to remove the localizations for languages you don't support in your app.