# iOS app displays more languages on the App Store than on Xcode

Tags: ios, xcode, app-store

We are building an application on iOS and published it to the App Store half a year ago. In recent weeks our app page has been showing several additional languages which are not part of our Xcode project. Is there any other way the code base determines what is part of the App Store page? Would very much appreciate any thought on this.

---

Here you see the languages on the App Store:

[image: App Store Page Languages]

---

And these are the languages we've created localized strings for on Xcode:

[image]

Comment: maybe this could help: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27240901/change-ios-app-list-of-supported-languages-in-app-store

Answer (score 1):

The languages your app is localised in, and the localised app store listings you have aren't connected.

For example, I could develop a non-localised app (English only), but localise my app store pages into French and German. So a French user would see an app store page in French, but the app would only show English (apart from system text, e.g. Done, Cancel buttons etc)

Or, I could localise my app into French and German, but not localise the app stores listing. A French user would see an English listing, but the app itself would contain French text.