# How to change the Language of my app in iTunes

Tags: codenameone

How to change the language of my app in iTunes?
I have searched the answer on Google, and it seems realated to info.plist.

[Change iOS App List of Supported Languages in App Store](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27240901/change-ios-app-list-of-supported-languages-in-app-store)

How do I set the language of my App on the App store with codename1?

Answer (score 0):

We have the build hint `ios.devLocale` which has the default value of `<string>English</string>`. You can try playing with it and add additional strings. I'm not sure if the syntax is `<string>English</string><string>Spanish</string>` etc. or `<string>English,Spanish</string>`.